# Unable to return PDO query result: Undefined Variable

Tags: php, pdo

I am having trouble outputting results from the following PDO query.  When I try to process the resultant array I am left with an "***Notice: Undefined variable: assets in...***" error message.

I've tried numerous incarnations of the function and output but cannot get it to work correctly.  Am I missing something here?

**THE QUERY**

```
function getAssets() {
global $dbc;
$query = "SELECT * FROM assets ORDER BY company ASC";
try {
    $statement = $dbc->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $assets = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $assets;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    display_db_error($error_message);
}
}
```

**THE VIEW**

```
//call function
getAssets();

//display the results
foreach($assets as $asset) {
echo '<tr><td><b>Region:</b></td><td>'.$asset['company'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

I've tested the array and when I use

```
print_r($assets);
```

It will print the entire array, but looping would be useful.  I've also tried fetching the data as an object to no avail.

Thank you! ... *and thanks for not waxing poetic about global variables :)*

Comment: GolezTrol's solution sounds right, but strange that `print_r($assets)` would work. Was that tested in the same scope as the foreach loop?

Comment: @MarkM Probably inside the function...

Comment: @GolezTrol Ya I guess it would have to have been

Comment: Yes was tested within function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$assets is a local variable in the function. To use it outside the function, you have to return it (which you do) *and* assign that result to a variable in the scope of the loop:

```
//call function and use it's result.
$assets = getAssets();
```

Comment: Figured it might be something trivial - that did the trick.  Bonehead mistake, thanks Golez!